# Can you disable that a button is clicked on enter

Tags: android, kotlin, barcode-scanner

So I am currently working on a scanner function and I need to read out a chain of key inputs.
The problem now is that whenever the scanner has completed scanning a code it presses Enter.
That in return triggers a click event on the currently focused item.

Is there any way to stop that from happening? So far I didn't find any information whatsoever on how to stop that from happening. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a key listener that does nothing:

```
view.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event -> 
    true
}
```

You return `true` meaning that you handled the event, while actually didn't do anything.